# Use finder to connect to IIS ftp server

Tags: finder, ftp

I would like to be able to use Finder to connect via (read-only) FTP to a IIS file server. However, I need to log in using the pattern `domain\username`. I've tried all the combinations I can think of to get this to work (`domain\username`, `domain\\username`, `domain%5cusername`) and none of them work. I have no problem connecting with the command line ftp client (though it's quirky), or any graphical clients. Has anyone been able to get this working for themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: In the end, I don't think it's possible. You have to use a third-party FTP client to pass domain information. That is extremely sad.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac I've actually had some trouble with FileZilla as Chris mentioned.

I personally prefer Cyberduck (http://cyberduck.ch/) which has worked very well for me. Especially in cases where Finder could not handle things like:

```
ftp://siteaddress|user@logindomain
```

Comment: I've used both CyberDuck and FileZilla, but I was really hoping to be able to do this through finder because it would seriously speed up my workflow. I find FileZilla to be dangerously buggy (if you have a staging server open in one tab and your production server in the other and open copies of the same file from each, it's painfully easy to accidentally overwrite the wrong one if you're not very careful). Cyberduck is a smoother experience, but I type in network paths a lot and FileZilla is much, much faster and easier for that.

Comment: @andrew Are you using Cyberduck's bookmarks?

Comment: Yes, but I would have dozens and dozens of them. It's faster and easier for me to type in the network paths myself. The reasons I can't really use cyberduck include: bookmarks are full login shortcuts, so each time I use one, I need to go through the login handshake process, which is slow (FileZilla has server- and path-type bookmarks) and Command-G allows you to type in a path and stores your last-used paths but long path names get cut off, so you can't see what you're looking selecting. For me, those are deal-breakers. Other than that, it's superior to FileZilla.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I've found is to use FileZilla. It's a free FTP program.

Domain\username is the best way to log in.
Just make sure to have the right settings when connecting to server.

IIS's FTP is kinda quriky sometimes, make sure you know what your doing, and try it on a windows client too!